# Get an yerror plot without a line in Octave

Tags: octave

I'd like to print a plot with y-error-bars and just plain points. My current Octave script looks like this:

```
errorbar(x_list, y_list, Delta_y_list, "~.x");
title("physikalisches Pendel");
xlabel("a^2 [m^2]");
ylabel("aT^2 [ms^2]");
print -dpdf plot.pdf
```

The plot I get has a line, although I specified the `.x` style option:

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/04/14/umbrella5.png

How can I get rid of that line?

And the ylabel is in the scale as well, is there some way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to set the linestyle:

```
p1 = errorbar(plot_x, plot_y, plot_error, "~.k");

set(p1, "linestyle", "none");
set(p1, "marker", "+");
```